# Use of std::istream::sentry with std::istream

Tags: c++, iostream

Consider the following simple program, which splits the input on whitespace and prints out the non-whitespace tokens one per line:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        while (std::cin)
        {
                std::string s;
                std::cin >> s;
                std::cout << "-" << s << "-\n";
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This works fine - except that, because the input stream only indicates EOF *after* we've attempted to read from it, when it reaches the end of the input stream (`^D`) it reads in and emits an empty string:

```
[begin]
< a b c
> -a-
> -b-
> -c-
< (^D)
> --
[end]
```

We can deal with this by making the output line conditional on `!s.empty()`.

However there's another option.  We can replace the line:

```
while (std::cin)
```

with:

```
while (std::istream::sentry(std::cin))
```

The sentry object (which is normally used internally by `operator>>`) has the effect of consuming whitespace and *then* checking for EOF or other stream states:

```
[begin]
< a b c
> -a-
> -b-
> -c-
< (^D)
[end]
```

My question is threefold:

- Is there any reason why this construct would not work as expected?
- Is it already idiomatic?
- If not, why not?

Comment: This is an inventive twist on the traditional "why is my `while (!strm.eof())` loop not working???" question! Though, ultimately, the answer is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::istream::sentry` is for use *inside* input functions. The proper fix to your problem is to *always* check that the stream is good, i.e. , the read was successful *after* reading:

```
for (std::string s; std::cin >> s; ) {
    std::cout << '-' << s << "-\n";
}
```

The stream can't know ahead of reading whether the read operation will be successful. After it is done, it just knows.

The approach using a `sentry` will normally work for strings but it can fail for types requiring any sort of formatting. For example, if you need to read an `int` skipping the space with the `sentry` does not indicate whether an `int` can be read. Even with `std::string`s the approach can fail: A stream could provide a character upon first access but fail upon second access. The first access is fir determining that the character isn't a space from `sentry`s constructor folowed by a failed read from the string.